# What is the size of a t-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_(statistics)) defines size of a test as the maximum probability of committing a type 1 error. And I'm very confused about how this is different than the significance level alpha. It seems to me the definition for both is P(rejecting null | null is true).

Is the size of a hypothesis test dependent on the type of test (z-test vs t-test), and does it depend on other parameters such as power, effect size?

Could you please explain this in the context of a t-test?

Thanks,

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203212/when-is-probability-of-type-i-error-less-than-the-level-of-significance/203215#203215

Comment: How come it's so similar to my answer ?! XD

Comment: @Peppershaker , I have fixed quite a few typos in my answer. Please let me know if it answers your query or not.

Comment: @Kolmogorov, surely foresight on my part when I posted it four years ago ;-). On a more serious note, given the many duplicate questions that aren't always identified as such, duplicate answers are also to be expected every now and then, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, you've $X_1, X_2, \cdots , X_n \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} N(\mu,1)$ , and you are testing $$H_0 : \mu \geqslant 0 \quad\text{against}\quad H_a : \mu < 0$$ Observe that the null hypothesis $H_0$ is a *composite hypothesis*, i.e. if $H_0$ is true, then for different values of $\mu~(\geqslant 0)$ , we shall obtain normal distributions with different parameters every time.

Therefore, for each possible value of $\mu~(\geqslant 0)$ , you get a different value of the type-I error (Size). For example, in this specific problem, there are uncountably many possible values of $\mu$ when $H_0$ is true. Now, **the *level of a test* is defined to be the supremum of the set of all possible type-I errors**. So, there may be infinitely many possible values of type-I errors. But the level will be a single real number, viz. the supremum of the set of all type-I errors.

Now, for the cases where $H_0$ is a *simple null hypothesis*, then the set of all possible type-I errors is just a singleton set. So, for that test, the level and type-I error are equal. e.g. suppose you're testing $$H_0 : \mu = 0 \quad\text{against}\quad H_a : \mu \neq 0$$ Then, the level and type-I error will indeed be equal.

---

Also, remember that the level or type-I errors of a test doesn't depend on its power, nor they are something special for different tests. They solely depend on the the type (Simple or Composite) of the null hypothesis $H_0$ , and also on the possible values that the concerned parameter may take if $H_0$ is true.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!